# List style not getting set to none in IE but applies in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, bootstrapper

I am facing a issue with styling of Ul in IE, but seems to work in chrome browser perfectly. 
Even after applying this style 
    **ul {
    list-style: none !important;
    }** 
it does not work in IE and I get a weird look for list element. My observation is this style of bootstrapper.css adds some style

```
*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
```

After toggling on this style in IE browser it removes the liststyle applied.

I also tried to add below css for elements  but still issue is not solved

> box-sizing:border-box

Please let me know if someone faced similar issue

Comment: try to force using the class/id.. ex: #idname ul li{list-style:none!important;}

Answer (score 0):

Add css list style property to li and try.

```
 ul li{
        list-style: none;
    }
```

Comment: No even adding those styles it didnt work. Its got to do something with Bootstrapper style for Nav element 
         `code`  *:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}   `code`
But what I cant figure out